# Custom route with htaccess php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Same as title, i want look like this:

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule / index.php?r=site&action=index
RewriteRule ^user/[0-9]+$ index.php?r=user&action=profile&user_id=$1
```

But it not working, example:

Url: 'http://mysite.domain/'

```
$route = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'r'); // $route = null;
```

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no slash when `/` is requested. The leading slash is removed from the URI when rules in htaccess files are processed. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)$ index.php?r=site&action=index [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/[0-9]+$ index.php?r=user&action=profile&user_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```